# Dynamic modelling of ammonia reactor using GEKKO IPOPT

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, reactor, gekko, ipopt

I am trying to do a dynamic simulation of ammonia reactor using GEKKO. Unfortunately, my code error says that it can't reach a solution. The equations I am trying to solve are steady-state in terms of species continuity equations but dynamic in terms of heat balance. I used the code shown below to first solve for the steady-state condition, which it does successfully by setting the IMODE = 1. However, when I import the steady-state results and used it to initialise my dynamic-state code, no solution is achieved. I do not understand how my code is not working when solving for the dynamic model since it worked fine for the steady-state model. I have tried IMODE = 4 and 7 but neither of them worked. Does anyone have any idea why my code is not working for the dynamic simulation?

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from GEKKO_single import n_store, P_store, xH2_store, xN2_store, xNH3_store, xinert_store, T_store, nr_store, Pr_store, xr_H2_store, xr_N2_store, xr_NH3_store, xr_inert_store, Tr_store

m = GEKKO()

#REACTOR BED PARAMETERS
stoi = [-3, -1, 2, 0]                                           # Reaction Stoichiometric coefficient [H2, N2, NH3, Ar]
Vbed_R1 = m.Const(0.7)                                          # Bed Volume [m3]
Vbed_R2 = m.Const(1.3)
rhocat = m.Const(2200)                                          # Density of catalyst [kg/m3]
Cp = m.Const(35500)                                             # Heat capacity of gas [J/(kmol K)]
Cpcat = m.Const(1100)                                           # Heat capacity of catalyst [J/(kg K)]
dHrx = m.Const(91.9836e6)                                       # Heat of reaction [J/kmol]
R = m.Const(8.314)                                              # Gas Constant [J/(mol K)]


#KINETIC PARAMETERS
Afor = m.Const(1.79e4)                                           # Forward reaction activity coefficient [kmole/(m3.hr.atm1.5)]
Abac = m.Const(2.57e16)                                          # Backward reaction activity coefficient [kmole.atm0.5/(m3.hr)]
Eafor = m.Const(87090)                                           # Forward reaction activation energy [J/mol]
Eabac = m.Const(198464)                                          # Backward reaction activation energy [J/mol]


# SPLITTER CONDITIONS
u1 = m.Const(0.2302) 
u2 = m.Const(0.2659) 
u3 = m.Const(0.5039)


#HEAT EXCHANGER
Cp_c = Cp
Cp_h = Cp
A_HX2 = m.Const(50)    
U =  m.Const(536)   


# FEED CONDITIONS 
nf = m.Const(0.4072)                                                 
Pf = m.Const(150.2780)                                           
Tf = m.Const(403.08370)                                                  # Temperature [K]                               
xf_H2 = m.Const(0.7050)                                                  # Mole fraction H2 [-]
xf_N2 = m.Const(0.2398)                                                  # Mole fraction N2 [-]
xf_NH3 = m.Const(0.0351)                                                 # Mole fraction NH3 [-]
xf_inert = m.Const(0.0202)                                               # Mole fraction inert [-]



#VOLUMETRIC COMPARTMENTS
ns_R1 = 20
ns_R2 = 20
ns = ns_R1 + ns_R2

#MASS OF THE CATALYST    
mcat_1 = (Vbed_R1/ns_R1)*rhocat                      # Mass of the catalyst [kg]
mcat_2 = (Vbed_R2/ns_R2)*rhocat 



#%% DEFINITIONS

#CONNECTION NUMBER
split_1 =   0
split_2 =   1
split_3 =   2
HX2_o   =   3
R1_i    =   4
R1_o    =   5
R2_i    =   6
R2_o    =   7

total   =   R2_o + 1


nt = int(3600*2)    #seconds
m.time = np.linspace(0,nt,nt)    #seconds


Pf = m.MV()
Pf.value = np.ones(nt) * Pf
Pf.value[1800:] = 120 #bar


 
#%% DEFINITION AND INITIALIZATION OF PARAMETERS 
 
 
# STEADY-STATE
n       = [m.Var(value = n_store[i],              lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
P       = [m.Var(value = P_store[i],                  lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
xH2     = [m.Var(value = xH2_store[i],    ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
xN2     = [m.Var(value = xN2_store[i],    ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
xNH3    = [m.Var(value = xNH3_store[i],   ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
xinert  = [m.Var(value = xinert_store[i], ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(total)]
T       = [m.Var(value = T_store[i],                  lb = 0) for i in range(total)]

 
 
# REACTOR BEDS
n_r       = [m.Var(value = nr_store[i],                  lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
P_r       = [m.Var(value = Pr_store[i],                  lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
xH2_r     = [m.Var(value = xr_H2_store[i],    ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
xN2_r     = [m.Var(value = xr_N2_store[i],    ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
xNH3_r    = [m.Var(value = xr_NH3_store[i],   ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
xinert_r  = [m.Var(value = xr_inert_store[i], ub = 1,    lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
T_r       = [m.Var(value = Tr_store[i],                  lb = 0) for i in range(ns)]
 
 


#%% SPLITTER 

#SPLITTER 1
m.Equation( n[split_1]         ==  u1 * nf   )
m.Equation( P[split_1]         ==  Pf        )
m.Equation( xH2[split_1]       ==  xf_H2     )
m.Equation( xN2[split_1]       ==  xf_N2     )
m.Equation( xNH3[split_1]      ==  xf_NH3    )
m.Equation( xinert[split_1]    ==  xf_inert  )
m.Equation( T[split_1]         ==  Tf        )

#SPLITTER 2
m.Equation( n[split_2]         ==  u2 * nf   )
m.Equation( P[split_2]         ==  Pf        ) 
m.Equation( xH2[split_2]       ==  xf_H2     ) 
m.Equation( xN2[split_2]       ==  xf_N2     ) 
m.Equation( xNH3[split_2]      ==  xf_NH3    ) 
m.Equation( xinert[split_2]    ==  xf_inert  ) 
m.Equation( T[split_2]         ==  Tf        )


#SPLITTER 3
m.Equation( n[split_3]         ==  u3 * nf   ) 
m.Equation( P[split_3]         ==  Pf        )
m.Equation( xH2[split_3]       ==  xf_H2     )
m.Equation( xN2[split_3]       ==  xf_N2     )
m.Equation( xNH3[split_3]      ==  xf_NH3    )
m.Equation( xinert[split_3]    ==  xf_inert  )
m.Equation( T[split_3]         ==  Tf        )
 


#%% HEAT EXCHANGER 2
NTU = m.Intermediate( U*A_HX2 / (n[split_3] * Cp_c) )
Cr  = m.Intermediate( n[split_3]*Cp_c / (n[R2_o]*Cp_h) )
Q   = m.Intermediate(  (n[split_3]  * Cp_c * (T[R2_o] - T[split_3]) )    *    (1 - m.exp(-NTU * (1-Cr)) ) / ( 1 - Cr * m.exp(-NTU * (1-Cr)) )   )


m.Equation(n[HX2_o]         ==  n[split_3]    )
m.Equation(P[HX2_o]         ==  P[split_3]    )
m.Equation(xH2[HX2_o]       ==  xH2[split_3]  )
m.Equation(xN2[HX2_o]       ==  xN2[split_3]  )
m.Equation(xNH3[HX2_o]      ==  xNH3[split_3] )
m.Equation(xinert[HX2_o]    ==  xinert[split_3] )
m.Equation(T[HX2_o]         ==  T[split_3] + (Q / (n[split_3]*Cp_c)) )



#%% MIXER 1 
m.Equation(n[R1_i]         ==  n[HX2_o] + n[split_1] )
m.Equation(P[R1_i]         ==  P[split_1] )
m.Equation(xH2[R1_i]       ==  (n[HX2_o]*xH2[HX2_o]     +  n[split_1]*xH2[split_1]) / n[R1_i] )
m.Equation(xN2[R1_i]       ==  (n[HX2_o]*xN2[HX2_o]     +  n[split_1]*xN2[split_1]) / n[R1_i] )
m.Equation(xNH3[R1_i]      ==  (n[HX2_o]*xNH3[HX2_o]    +  n[split_1]*xNH3[split_1]) / n[R1_i] )
m.Equation(xinert[R1_i]    ==  (n[HX2_o]*xinert[HX2_o]  +  n[split_1]*xinert[split_1]) / n[R1_i] )
m.Equation(T[R1_i]         ==  (n[HX2_o]*T[HX2_o]       +  n[split_1]*T[split_1]) / n[R1_i])


#%% REACTOR BED 1
 
#FIRST COMPARTMENT
m.Equation(n_r[0]              ==      n[R1_i] )
m.Equation(P_r[0]              ==      P[R1_i] )
m.Equation(n_r[0]*xH2_r[0]     ==      n[R1_i]*xH2[R1_i] )
m.Equation(n_r[0]*xN2_r[0]     ==      n[R1_i]*xN2[R1_i] )
m.Equation(n_r[0]*xNH3_r[0]    ==      n[R1_i]*xNH3[R1_i] )
m.Equation(n_r[0]*xinert_r[0]  ==      n[R1_i]*xinert[R1_i] )
m.Equation(T_r[0]              ==      T[R1_i] )

 
 
#MIDDLE COMPARTMENTS  
m.Equations([n_r[i]                         ==  (n_r[i-1] + sum(stoi)*mcat_1* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat))  for i in range(1,ns_R1) ])
m.Equations([P_r[i]                         ==  P_r[i-1]  for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xH2_r[i]                ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xH2_r[i-1]+mcat_1* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[0]))  for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xN2_r[i]                ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xN2_r[i-1]+mcat_1* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[1]))  for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xNH3_r[i]               ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xNH3_r[i-1]+mcat_1* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[2]))  for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xinert_r[i]             ==  (n_r[i-1]*xinert_r[i-1])  for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
m.Equations([(mcat_1*Cpcat)* T_r[i].dt()    ==  (Cp*(n_r[i-1]*T_r[i-1] - n_r[i]*T_r[i]) + (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*mcat_1*dHrx) for i in range(1,ns_R1)])
  


#PASS THE LAST VALUE
m.Equation(n[R1_o]        ==  n_r[ns_R1-1]      )
m.Equation(P[R1_o]        ==  P_r[ns_R1-1]      )
m.Equation(xH2[R1_o]      ==  xH2_r[ns_R1-1]    )
m.Equation(xN2[R1_o]      ==  xN2_r[ns_R1-1]    )
m.Equation(xNH3[R1_o]     ==  xNH3_r[ns_R1-1]   )
m.Equation(xinert[R1_o]   ==  xinert_r[ns_R1-1] )
m.Equation(T[R1_o]        ==  T_r[ns_R1-1]      )


    
#%% MIXER 2
m.Equation(n[R2_i]         ==  n[R1_o] + n[split_2])
m.Equation(P[R2_i]         ==  P[split_2] )
m.Equation(xH2[R2_i]       ==  (n[R1_o]*xH2[R1_o]     +  n[split_2]*xH2[split_2]) / n[R2_i] )
m.Equation(xN2[R2_i]       ==  (n[R1_o]*xN2[R1_o]     +  n[split_2]*xN2[split_2]) / n[R2_i] )
m.Equation(xNH3[R2_i]      ==  (n[R1_o]*xNH3[R1_o]    +  n[split_2]*xNH3[split_2]) / n[R2_i] )
m.Equation(xinert[R2_i]    ==  (n[R1_o]*xinert[R1_o]  +  n[split_2]*xinert[split_2]) / n[R2_i] )
m.Equation(T[R2_i]         ==  (n[R1_o]*T[R1_o]       +  n[split_2]*T[split_2]) / n[R2_i])

    
 
#%% REACTOR BED 2
 
#FIRST COMPARTMENT
m.Equation(n_r[ns_R1]                  ==      n[R2_i] )
m.Equation(P_r[ns_R1]                  ==      P[R2_i]  )
m.Equation(n_r[ns_R1]*xH2_r[ns_R1]     ==      n[R2_i]*xH2[R2_i]  )
m.Equation(n_r[ns_R1]*xN2_r[ns_R1]     ==      n[R2_i]*xN2[R2_i]  )
m.Equation(n_r[ns_R1]*xNH3_r[ns_R1]    ==      n[R2_i]*xNH3[R2_i]  )
m.Equation(n_r[ns_R1]*xinert_r[ns_R1]  ==      n[R2_i]*xinert[R2_i]  )
m.Equation(T_r[ns_R1]                  ==      T[R2_i])
 
 
 
#MIDDLE COMPARTMENTS  
m.Equations([n_r[i]                         ==  (n_r[i-1] + sum(stoi)*mcat_2* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat))  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns) ])
m.Equations([P_r[i]                         ==  P_r[i-1]  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xH2_r[i]                ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xH2_r[i-1]+mcat_2* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[0]))  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xN2_r[i]                ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xN2_r[i-1]+mcat_2* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[1]))  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xNH3_r[i]               ==  ((n_r[i-1]*xNH3_r[i-1]+mcat_2* (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*stoi[2]))  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
m.Equations([n_r[i]*xinert_r[i]             ==  (n_r[i-1]*xinert_r[i-1])  for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
m.Equations([(mcat_2*Cpcat)* T_r[i].dt()    ==  (Cp*(n_r[i-1]*T_r[i-1] - n_r[i]*T_r[i]) + (4.75*( Afor*m.exp(-Eafor/(R*T_r[i]))  *  xN2_r[i]*P_r[i]  *  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) / (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i]) - Abac*m.exp(-Eabac/(R*(T_r[i])))  *  (xNH3_r[i]*P_r[i])  /  ((xH2_r[i]*P_r[i])**1.5) )/3600/rhocat)*mcat_2*dHrx) for i in range(ns_R1+1, ns)])
  
      
#PASS THE LAST VALUE
m.Equation(n[R2_o]        ==  n_r[ns-1])
m.Equation(P[R2_o]        ==  P_r[ns-1] )
m.Equation(xH2[R2_o]      ==  xH2_r[ns-1] )
m.Equation(xN2[R2_o]      ==  xN2_r[ns-1] )
m.Equation(xNH3[R2_o]     ==  xNH3_r[ns-1] )
m.Equation(xinert[R2_o]   ==  xinert_r[ns-1] )
m.Equation(T[R2_o]        ==  T_r[ns-1])

 


#%% SOLVE DYNAMIC MODEL
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(debug=0)


#PLOT MY GEKKO RESULTS
plt.figure()
t = m.time
plt.plot(t/60, T_r[-1])
plt.xlabel("Time [minutes]")
plt.ylabel("Temperature [K]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GEKKO_single` is missing so the script is missing the configuration parameters. Here are some tips in absence of any verification:

1. Set a smaller time horizon to see if it will complete a solution:

```py
nt = 60    #seconds
m.time = np.linspace(0,nt,nt)    #seconds
```

2. Initialize with `COLDSTART=2`:

```py
m.options.COLDSTART=2
m.solve()
```

This can take longer to solve but generally does a better job of finding an initial solution.

3. Initialize with `IMODE=1`:

```py
m.options.IMODE=1
m.solve()

m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve()
```

This should also work but you may need to transfer values from the steady state solution if you previously set the `value` property for variables when you defined the problem.

If you can post the `GEKKO_single` configuration parameters then we can give more specific feedback by verifying the methods.

Comment: Suggestion 3 worked for me. Thank you very much